# Ajax поиск laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь присоединить ajax поиск по сущности к сортировке в один запрос.
Сущность содержит поля firstmane и lastname, к примеру.
Выполнить поиск по одному полю не трудно, как то так:

```
$users = User::where('firstname', 'LIKE', $request->firstname)->get();
```

Но как лучше всего организовать поиск по базе по разным полям сущности в одной строке на фронтенде? Например строка "Сергей Ива" возвращал строки Сергея Иванова, Сергея Иванченко И так далее.

Есть идеи в сторону регклярных выражений, но может есть более простые методы?

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно искать по firstname + lastname, то в запросе их объединяйте в одно поле и уже по этому полю ищите.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) as fullname FROM users where fullname like '%имя пользователя%'
```

Если же нужен поиск по нескольким полям одновременно - смотрите в сторону полнотекстового поиска, реализуется достаточно просто одним запросом. Не забудьте проставить индексы в таблице.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так :

```
protected function search(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $data = User::where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->paginate(15);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if (App::environment('local')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        return responseJSON('DB ERROR', 'error');
    }

    return view('home.index')
        ->with(['data' => $data]);
}
```